# Could not complete "horizon db init" exec failed: pq: unrecognized configuration parameter "lock_timeout"

Tags: horizon, postgres

I get the following error on running the command -  horizon db init. My Horizon install is compiled from the source for CentOS 7 following https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/admin.html .

> ERRO[0000] exec failed: pq: unrecognized configuration parameter "lock_timeout"  pid=8107

I understand this is related to the lower version of Postgres on my server. I have a bunch of issues with upgrading to Postgres 9.3 or above. I tried hard to edit the SQL schema files that horizon db init uses. But all my attempt ends in futile.

I even ran,

> "$ find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/SET lock_timeout = 0;/;/g' {} \;"

from horizon repository before running

> "$ go install github.com/stellar/go/services/horizon" .

I would like to know what changes to horizon source code (I'm using devel branch) would help me get rid of "lock_timeout" error without having to upgrade the Postgres.

Comment: Horizon requires Postgres >=9.3. More info https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question answered by bartekn at https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/461

> Horizon requires Postgres >= 9.3. It's possible that other parts of
>   the system won't work as expected, even if you manage to pass horizon
>   db init command.